EMI/EMC: Connecting PCB mounting holes to chassis in multi-board system
I am working on a system which has a metal chassis connected to the earth. The system gets power from a dedicated PSU. The power lines of the PSU (VCC_PSU / GND_PSU) are fed into a master PCB and power supply noise is filtered out using a common mode choke and some capacitors. This filtered power line is named Signal_VCC / Signal_GND.
The master PCB mounting holes all plated and are connected to GND_PSU. The idea is to use the master board as a type of power hub, with a star grounding to the chassis.
The system also has multiple daughter PCBs which accomplish different functions. Each daughter PCB is connected using cables to the master PCB, which provides a good return path for GND, as well as Signal_VCC and some data lines (UART, GPIO, I2C).
I want to know, for best EMI immunity and radiation, what is the best way to ground the daughter PCBs? Should I connect the mounting holes (which are connected to chassis) to Signal_GND or would that create unwanted ground loops?
Instead of passing Signal_VCC / Signal_GND to each daughter board should I instead pass VCC_PSU / GND_PSU, and the connect the mounting holes to the chassis?


How to best connect them depends on basically everything. You have not mentioned the properties of the power supply, and, if the metal box has any other connectors/interfaces to outside world, except for the mains inlet. Are there any ports for external devices, or any other user interfaceable actuators etc on the device, or is it just a metal cube with mains inlet?

Is the chassis contiguous, i.e. is it solid metal (sheet or etc.) underneath where the cables are routed? How are the cables routed within the enclosure, do they follow walls, or just kind of jump around in space? Do the daughter PCBs have any other electrical connections, or are they stand-alone (all connections are as shown)? What kind of standards will this device have to pass?  Would commercial CE test levels suffice? (say 3V conducted, 3V/m radiated)?

The power supply is certified OEM equipment providing various power rails, which connect directly to the master PCB as shown. The chassis has no connectors other than a mains socket. There is a lot of different equipment in the chassis which interface whith the daughter boards (motors/ lights etc.).

The chassis is contiguous, the cable are routed close to the chassis walls wherever possible? The daughter boards have other connections, such as one can control a motor, the other can control lights etc. Commercial CE would suffice

Could you expand the diagram to include all boards, or at least a representative sampling of them? How are the motor, light, etc. driven: is there a (functional) EMI concern there?
